# Manipulating state with useEffect, but not correctly rendering updated from updated state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I am building a new portfolio site out of a few new (to me) technologies and am running into an issue where I can set the initial state fine using `useState` React hook, but when I update the state, it is not rendering from the new state. I was attempting to use `useEffect` but have since removed it but I am beginning to think I am missing some core concept of implementation for this hooksand would appreciate any advice or recommended reading to help me over this hurdle. My code is as follows ( I apologize in advance for the terrible typescript, as that is one of the things I am attempting to learn, and appreciate any advice there as well):

**index.tsx** UPDATED

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import { useState } from 'react';
import Body from '../components/Body'
import HeaderItem from "../components/HeaderItem"
import {
    UserCircleIcon,
    CollectionIcon,
    BeakerIcon,
} from '@heroicons/react/outline'


type BodyProps = {
  image: string,
  text: string,
}

const Intro= {
  image: 'https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/2357717?v=4',
  text: 'Hello this is gonna be the new INTRO body! Hopefully using the body as a component will make single page transitions cleaner'
}

const Skills = {
  image: 'https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/2357717?v=4',
  text: 'Hello this is gonna be the new SKILL body! Hopefully using the body as a component will make single page transitions cleaner'
}


export default function Home({ image, text }: BodyProps) {
  const [ currentDisplay, setCurrentDisplay ] = useState(Intro);

  const handleClick = (display) => {
    setCurrentDisplay({
      image: display.image,
      text: display.text
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="">
      <Head>
        <title>Eric Anderson</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      
      <header className='flex flex-col sm:flex-row m-5 justify-between items-center'>
        <h1 className="text-2xl pb-10">ERIC ANDERSON</h1>
        <div className='flex flex-row justify-evenly max-w-2xl'>
        
          <HeaderItem handleClick={() => handleClick(Intro)} Icon={UserCircleIcon} title='Intro' />

          <HeaderItem handleClick={() => handleClick(Skills)} Icon={BeakerIcon} title='Skills' />

          <HeaderItem  Icon={CollectionIcon} title='Github' />

        </div>
      </header> 
      {/* Header - Name github  Intro Skills */}
      <Body display={currentDisplay}/>
      {/* Body req: image=svg && text=string */}
    </div>
  )
}
```

**components/Body.tsx** UPDATED

```
type BodyProps = {
    image: string,
    text: string,
}

function Body({ display }: BodyProps) {
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
            <img
                className="rounded-full mb-10" 
                src={display.image} alt="" />
           <p className="text-white mx-10">{display.text}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export

default Body
```

**components/HeaderItem.tsx**

```
type HeaderProps = {
    title: string,
    Icon: any,
    handleClick?: any,
}

function HeaderItem({title, Icon, handleClick}: HeaderProps ) {
 
    return (
        <button
            onClick={handleClick} 
            className="flex flex-col items-center cursor-pointer group w-12 sm:w-20 hover:text-white">
            <Icon className='h-8 mb-1 group-hover:animate-bounce '/>
            <h1 className='opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100 tracking-widest'>{title}</h1>
        </button>
    )
}

export default HeaderItem
```

The end goal is for the image and text of the `<Body >` component to be updated to the new values when the appropriate button is clicked, i. e. when the Skills button is clicked, I would like the state to be updated from the Skills variable and display the associated text and image in the Body component. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't believe the 'useEffect' is needed at all. Are you able to try and pass through your entire 'currentDisplay' object, rather than it's properties. So '<Body display={currentDisplay} />' and then deconstruct that in the Body component

Comment: So, following your advice, I changed to ```<Body display={currentDisplay}/> ``` in index.tsx and in my Body component, i passed in ({ currentDisplay }) to the body and ```src={currentDisplay.image}``` and ```{currentDisplay.text}```. I get an undefined 'image" error pointing at ```src={currentDisplay.image}```

Comment: not sure you need useEffect. you might even be creating an infinite loop by updating the state that you are observing in the useEffect. 
add a console.log() inside your handleClick function, I don't think its being called.
usually need to do something like this
            onClick={() => handleClick(index)}

Comment: I added the console log and you are right, ```handleClick``` is not being called. I thought i could pass that function down as a prop to the HeaderItem and invoke it there but apparently that is not working the way i thought either. I did realize I was using implementations for both functional components and class components, so hopefully in resolving that, it will shed some more light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lay in the way I was passing props between from the state object into the Body component, and was exposed by naming things more idomatically, particularly renaming `handleClick` into `onClick` and passing it into HeaderItem as `<button onClick={onClick}....` and in `index.tsx`, passing it like so

```
<HeaderItem onClick={() =>onClick(Intro)}...

<HeaderItem onClick={() => onClick(Skills)}...
```

This allowed me to invoke the function correctly on click which updated my state object and passes the display down to the child Body component, where it is destructed into an image and text. Thank you for the help everyone, for both resolving the issue I had and teaching me along the way